# How to get only the columns that have at least one non-null value in a table existing in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table named Product with following data for instance:

| p_id | p_name | p_cat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | shirt | null |
| 2 | null | null |
| 3 | cap | null |

Suppose I don't know numbre of rows and columns in the table as well as I don't know which columns are compltely null (no non-null value in all of its rows). How to write a query to retrieve just the columns that have atleast one non-null value in its rows. My approach is as follows but not getting a corret output:

```
select
column_name
into #TempColumns
from information_schema.columns
where 
table_name = 'Product'
and table_schema = 'DDB'
declare @CurrentColumn nvarchar(max) = '', @IsNull bit, @NonNullCols nvarchar(max) = ''
declare Cur cursor for 
select column_name from #TempColumns
open Cur

while 1=1
begin
fetch next from Cur into @CurrentColumn
select @IsNull = case when count(@CurrentColumn) > 0 then 0 else 1 end
from Product

if @IsNull = 1
begin 
set @NonNullCols = @NonNullCols + ',' + @CurrentColumn
end
if @@fetch_status <> 0 break
end
close Cur
deallocate Cur
select @NonNullCols as NullColumns
drop table #TempColumns
```

If there is any other approach or correction in my above (T-SQL) query. Thanks in advance.

First I just create a temporary table to store all the column names avaialbe in the Product table. Then I looped in this temporary table and feteched each row and checked it on the product table whether the column is comptely null or not using the count() function. The condition sets the bit variable 1 if the column is completely null and then that particular column name is stored in anothe variable which is then retrieved as null columns.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: This is very strange requirement but it would require dynamic sql to work.

Comment: You won't be able to do this in one step. The SQL language has a strict rule that you must include column information at query compile time, before looking at **any** table data. So you can write a query to tell you which columns you want, but you can't then also select from just those columns at the same time. That will need to be  a separate step.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a conceptual example for you.

It is using SQL Server XML and XQuery powers without dynamic SQL and cursors/loops.

The algorithm is very simple.
When we are converting each row into XML, columns that hold NULL value are missing from the XML.

**SQL**

```
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tmpTable;

CREATE TABLE #tmpTable (
     client_id int,
     client_name varchar(500),
     client_surname varchar(500),
     city varchar(500),
     state varchar(500));
    
INSERT #tmpTable VALUES
(1,'Miriam',NULL,'Las Vegas',NULL),
(2,'Astrid',NULL,'Chicago',NULL),
(3,'David',NULL,'Phoenix',NULL),
(4,'Hiroki',NULL,'Orlando',NULL);

SELECT DISTINCT x.value('local-name(.)', 'SYSNAME') AS NotNULLColumns
FROM #tmpTable AS t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.* FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t1(c)
    CROSS APPLY c.nodes('/root/*') AS t2(x);
```

**SQL #2**

To handle edge cases.

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.value('local-name(.)', 'SYSNAME') AS NotNULLColumns
FROM #tmpTable AS t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.* FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS, BINARY BASE64, TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t1(c)
    CROSS APPLY c.nodes('/root/row/*') AS t2(x);
```

**Output**

| NotNULLColumns |
| --- |
| city |
| client_id |
| client_name |

Comment: I am getting this error: FOR XML could not serialize the data for node 'ExtractedText' because it contains a character (0x000C) which is not allowed in XML. To retrieve this data using FOR XML, convert it to binary, varbinary or image data type and use the BINARY BASE64 directive.

Comment: From the very beginning, I asked (in the comments) to provide a minimal reproducible example: ##1-4

Comment: Please try SQL #2.